# Attaching a plugins gui to the hosts gui

Tags: user-interface, plugins, window, shared

I'm writing an application with plugin support. I use C++ and JUCE for that stuff and I want my application to run on windows and MAC OSX (and maybe linux some day).

My plugins have their own GUI. The usual way to display a GUI from a shared library seems to be :

1. create a new window
2. get the native handle for it
3. pass it on to the library
4. let the library attach its GUI to that handle.

AFAIK that always requires to create a new window for the plugins GUI. My problem is: I would like to have the GUI of the plugins to appear ***inside*** the GUI of my host application (= not as a separate window).

**I think this is a common thing to do, but I just can't find any concepts for that. How would you solve such a problem?**

Thank you very much for ideas and hints!